# Containers are not linked with docker-compose version 2

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that I upgraded from version 1 to version 2.

It set ups a simple Selenium hub with a firefox node.

When I set it up as version 1 it launches fine. When I set it up with version 2 the ff container returns `"Not linked with a running Hub container"` and exits.

As I researched it and understood it , is that the linkage between the containers somehow suffers.

Is there a solution ?? Am I missing something ??

```
version: '2'
services:
  hub:
    container_name: hub
    image: selenium/hub 
    ports:
      - "8080:4444" # HOST:CONTAINER
    expose:
      - "4444" 

  ff:
    container_name: ff
    image: selenium/node-firefox 
    links:
      - hub
    expose:
      - "5555"
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add an environment variable to your `ff` section of the Docker Compose file (and you can remove the link):

```
ff:
  container_name: ff
  image: selenium/node-firefox
  environment:
    - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
  expose:
    - "5555"
```

Compose version 2 uses a different style of networking. From the [upgrading guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#upgrading):

> environment variables created by `links` have been deprecated for some
>   time. In the new Docker network system, they have been removed. You
>   should either connect directly to the appropriate hostname or set the
>   relevant environment variable yourself, using the link hostname.

From the [networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/):

> `links` are not required to enable services to communicate - by
>   default, any service can reach any other service at that service’s
>   name.

The Selenium dockerfile uses version 1 style networking by ENV variable. Here in the [code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/ceb17d8f9fca6936696a2c7fbd1004f3eba6cb4c/NodeBase/entry_point.sh#L9), if that variable isn't set (which Docker used to do) the entry_point.sh command exits. Providing the variable explicitly solves this.

Comment: Thanks for the response JCotton. I must admit that I have read the docker documentation you link to , many times. It is not clear the concept you explain so nice. I traced the problem to the line you point but could not make something with it.  It worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: I must also add another thing that I noticed when switching from v1 to v2 compose file. Beware that the networking changes so the container IPs change too. What in v1 may be 172.17.0.3 , in v2 becomes 172.18.0.4 . It gave me a headache until I figured it out.

Comment: Same here. Docker has many facets and changes so fast. Smart people are making good improvements but it's difficult to understand everything if you aren't working with it full time. (Glad this helped. Consider [upvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/142472) as well. ^_^)

Comment: this answer was well explained ,helped me in debugging my issue

Comment: For everyone reading this answer and still finding their grid nodes refuse to connect, try adding `- HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444` to the environment section of each node.

Comment: @ciruvan may we know more ?

Answer (score 0):

Below compose file working for me

```
# To execute this docker-compose yml file use docker-compose -f <file_name> up
# Add the "-d" flag at the end for deattached execution

version: '2'
services:
  firefoxnode:
    image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: hub
    ports:
      - "32772:5900"

  chromenode:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      HUB_HOST: hub
    ports:
      - "32773:5900"

  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

command I use:

```
 docker-compose -f .\docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Source :

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium