# How to start selenium hub and one linked node via docker-compose instead of using docker?

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose

I can start a selenium hub image via:

```
docker run --rm=true -P -p 4444:4444  --name selenium-hub selenium/hub
```

and add a firefox worker via:

```
docker run --rm=true --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-firefox
```

Going on http://localhost:4444/grid/console then will show the grid just fine.

I don't want to use docker each time but have the same setup via `docker-compose`.

Hence, I thought I could just do this in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
selenium_hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports: ["4444:4444"]
    links:
        - selenium_firefox_worker
selenium_firefox_worker:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
```

Yet after running `docker-compose up` I get the message:

```
selenium_firefox_node_1 | Not linked with a running Hub container
selenium_firefox_node_1 exited with code 1
```

and hence the grid doesn't show any node.

I thought that I may be doing the linking in the wrong order, yet even:

```
selenium_hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports: ["4444:4444"]
selenium_firefox_node:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    links:
        - selenium_hub
```

yields in the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's the host name. Might you be trying to connect to a hostname "hub", but the link you're creating is actually "selenium_firefox_worker"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
selenium_hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports: ["4444:4444"]
selenium_firefox_node:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    links:
        - "selenium_hub:hub"
```

While [k0pernikus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36457717/457268) does work, I just wanted to elaborate on the reason why it was failing.

The node containers expect to connect to a hub which is resolvable as simply:

```
hub
```

rather than in their example where it will be resolvable as:

```
selenium_hub
```

Answer (score 9):

As a side note, if using docker-compose version 2 format you have to specify a couple env variables, otherwise the node will not connect to the hub:

```
version: '2'
services:
    hub:
        image: selenium/hub
        ports:
            - "4444:4444"

    firefox:
        image: selenium/node-firefox
        environment:
            HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: hub
            HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT: 4444
        links:
            - hub
```

Credits:
[Containers are not linked with docker-compose version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087173/containers-are-not-linked-with-docker-compose-version-2)

Comment: Works with version '2.1' also

Answer (score 5):

[Stumbling across this tutorial](http://carlosbecker.com/posts/selenium-grid-docker-compose), there was this syntax provided. And even though it's similar to one of my approaches, it worked.

```
hub:
  image: selenium/hub
  ports:
    - "4444:4444"
firefox:
  image: selenium/node-firefox
  links:
    - hub
chrome:
  image: selenium/node-chrome
  links:
    - hub
```

It's seems to be something about the naming, yet am not sure.