# Docker Compose won't start Selenium Grid

Tags: docker, docker-compose, selenium-grid

I have the following Docker Compose file

```
version: "3"

services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=selenium-hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
  devenv:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

When I run the Docker Compose file without:

```
  devenv:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

It works fine and Selenium Grid will successfully stand up. When I introduce this service however, the grid won't stand up, the tests will attempt to run but of course there is no grid so it will then fail.

Where am I going wrong?

Docker file called at build .

```
FROM maven
RUN apt update
COPY . /

RUN mvn clean test
```

> error message: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457363/how-to-start-selenium-hub-and-one-linked-node-via-docker-compose-instead-of-usin?rq=1

Comment: Recommendation: You can link the nodes instead of setting the address and port.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you follow the below steps -

**Prerequisite:**

- Java-8
- Docker Desktop client
- UI Test Project

Let's assume your Test Project uses TestNG to run its selenium scripts.

**Step 1:** Modify your BaseTest or Test starter class to initialize RemoteWebDriver.

Replace or add the below code to your BaseTest or wherever your Browser Driver initialization happens.

```
 @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTestSetup() throws MalformedURLException {

    MutableCapabilities dc = new ChromeOptions();

    host = System.getenv("HUB_HOST") != null ? System.getenv("HUB_HOST") : "hub";

    driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://" + host + ":4444/wd/hub"), dc));

    logger.info("Remote Chrome Driver Started...");

    driver.get().manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.get().manage().window().maximize();

    }
```

**Step 2:** Add Maven Plugins to your pom.xml to create executable jars.

We will need to add the below plugins in order to generate an executable jar for our Test Project.

- maven-compiler-plugin
- maven-dependency-plugin
- maven-jar-plugin

View the below snippet for example -

```html
<build>
  <finalName>dockerized</finalName>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>copy-dependencies</id>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>
              ${project.build.directory}/libs
            </outputDirectory>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>test-jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.18.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
          <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
        <argLine>
          -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
        </argLine>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

**Step 3:** Add a **healthcheck.sh** script

The healthcheck script is needed to check the Grid availability to receive test requests before running our tests.

```
echo "Checking if hub is ready - $HUB_HOST"

while [ "$( curl -s http://$HUB_HOST:4444/wd/hub/status | jq -r .value.ready )" != "true" ]
do
    sleep 1
done
```

**Step 4:** Add a **run.sh** script

```
java -cp dockerized.jar:dockerized-tests.jar:libs/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

**Step 5:** Create a **docker-compose.yml** file

```
version: "3"
services:
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.1.3
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"

  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.1.3
    shm_size: '3gb'
    depends_on:
      - hub
    links:
      - hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1

  test-run:
    build: .
    container_name: test-run
    depends_on:
      - chrome
    links:
      - hub
    environment:
      - MODULE=testng.xml
    volumes:
      - ./src/test/resources/results:/app
```

**Step 6:** Create a **Dockerfile** to instruct the creation of your Docker Image

We will use multiple base images in multi-stage builds to create the final image. The first stage (named **package**) will generate the executable jars and the second stage (named **testrun**) will run these executable jars.

Do note the different base images being used in each stage as required.

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8-alpine AS package

RUN apk add --update \
    curl \
    jq

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY pom.xml                          .
COPY healthcheck.sh                   .
RUN mvn -e -B dependency:resolve

COPY src                              ./src
RUN mvn verify --fail-never -DskipTests

WORKDIR /app/

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]
CMD ["healthcheck.sh"]

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine AS testrun

RUN mkdir -p /jar
WORKDIR /jar/

COPY --from=package /app/target/dockerized.jar         .
COPY --from=package /app/target/dockerized-tests.jar   .
COPY --from=package /app/target/libs                        ./libs
COPY testng.xml                                             .
COPY run.sh                                                 .

WORKDIR /jar/

ENV HUB_HOST=hub
ENV MODULE=testng.xml

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]
CMD ["run.sh"]
```

**Step 7:** Finally, run your docker-compose

Open Powershell in your project root folder and run the below command.

```
***docker-compose up --build***
```

Sample Project Link - https://gitlab.com/suryajit7/my-blog-topics